# Maintain control of the console input while validating user entry

Tags: c#

I need to modify this for a comma-separated string. I want the user to be able to enter multiple numbers but I need to validate they are all numbers before I continue. Any thoughts?

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid Number!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up with

```
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var entry = Console.ReadLine();
            List<int> myNumbers = entry.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
            serializedValue = _unitOfWork.GetSerializedCollection(myNumbers);
            Console.WriteLine(serializedValue);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.Write("You must enter a  number.");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just implemenent custom method for parsing integer arrays and use it in the same way:

```
void Main()
{
    while (!TryParseIntegerArray(Console.ReadLine(), out var arr))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a valid integer or comma-separated string!");   
    }

    // work with arr here
}

bool TryParseIntegerArray(string input, out int[] arr)
{
    if (input == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

    try
    {
        arr = input.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(int.Parse)
                   .ToArray();
        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        arr = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, I wouldn't recomment using `Console.ReadLine()` directly as an argument, either for `TryParseIntegerArray` and `int.TryParse`. You need to check it for null, at least. For example:

```
string input;
int[] arr;

do
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Good bye!");
        return;
    }
} while (!TryParseIntegerArray(input, out arr));
```

Comment: thanks Yeldar. I'm working through a potential solution right now. This has potential as well. I do agree with you about Console.Readline(). It's been years since I had to mess around with Console programming. You forget what you forgot. :)